# How to remove an item from index N with FSharpx's PersistentVector?

Tags: f#, immutable-collections, fsharpx

I notice that the PersistentVector from FSharpX has no remove at index method.

https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-persistentvector-1.html

It has the ability to modify the item at the nth location but no ability to remove it. This seems like a strange omission. If it is not possible then can somebody suggest a different immutable persistent collection that has this ability.

My current code for removing at item at *id* from the vector is brute force

```
            state 
            |> Seq.indexed 
            |> Seq.where ( fun (_id,_)->id<>_id) 
            |> Seq.map (fun (_,p)->p) 
            |> PersistentVector.ofSeq
```

Note that I'm trying to use PersistentVector as a backing store for a UI. I'm experimenting with https://github.com/JaggerJo/Avalonia.FuncUI which is an Elmish port for Avalonia. I got quite far and then wanted to add a delete button on a row and I can't find a way to update my backing store. :(

Example code for the UI is

https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/77f3fcb8e660783790c5610290cd8d97

Comment: The design of PersistentVector makes it impossible to remove items from the middle in less than O(N) time. To add that, you'd need to have a different design, such as a Relaxed Radix-Balanced Vector or RRBVector. I'm currently (as in, right now as I type this I'm running unit tests) working on an RRBVector implementation for F#, and I hope to release an alpha within the next month or so. It will include efficient inserting into, and removing from, the middle of the vector. Watch https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections/issues/72 to be notified when I release it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think any of the collections in FSharpx.Collections support delete, except PersistentHashMap, which has a remove method. 
I'm sure there are some collections in FSharpx.Experimental.Collections that also support remove/delete. These may not be useful for you.

You might want to look at this new project for what you are attempting https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.Adaptive